# eth0 will not connect to mirror port on switch

Tags: ubuntu, switch

I have a Ubuntu setup with 3 network interface and I also have a HP Procurve switch with port 1 configured as a mirroring port.

However, eth0 does not connect when I plug a cable to port 1. When I plug to port 2 or port 3, Ubuntu is able to connect and grab IP from the DHCP server.

Is there something wrong here?

Comment: How did you check that the eth0 is not connected when connected the mirror port?

Comment: Hi migabi, Ubuntu will state that eth0 is connected through a prompt on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try a setting up a different port than 1 as mirror. And try wether you can connect to port 1 in normal mode. If that doesn't work, port 1 may be damaged.

Also check the Procurve's manual about the implications of setting up a port as mirror port (While unlikely; does it disable autonegotiation by chance?).

Try forcing both the client and switch to a specific (same!) speed/duplex mode. If it works now, you had a b0rked (read mismatching) autonegotiation setting on one of those two. (Usually, speed *and* duplex mode should be configured to be set up by autonegotiation).

(There is also the slight possibilty that you need to use a crossover cable, but since most interfaces today do Auto-MDIX, I state this merely for the sake of completeness).

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for your reply. I have tried assigning port 5 as a mirror port but it still does not work. I have also tried manually configuring the speed / duplex mode as well as using a crossover cable but none of it work.